# Fibonacci calculation

Tags: java, numbers, fibonacci

This program is supposed to get a Fibonacci number from the user and the program will calculate what it is while making sure that the user entered a positive number and a number no less than the Fibonacci number 70. So, if the user entered 7, it should print 13. The method fibcalc() is supposed to do the calculations. 
When I try and compile the program, I get the errors "method fibcalc in class Fibonacci cannot be applied to given types: `System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %f", num, fibcalc(num, x3));` and "cannot find symbol" `return x3;`Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci
{
    public static void main ( String args[] ) 
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

        int num; 
        double x3 = 0;


           System.out.print("Which Fibonacci number would you like? ");
       num = input.nextInt(); 
           do
       {
        System.out.print("Which Fibonacci number would you like? ");
        num = input.nextInt(); 
    }while(num >= 0 && num <= 70);

    System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %f", num, fibcalc(num, x3));

}


public static double fibcalc(int num) 
{
    int x1 = 0;
    int x2 = 1;

        if (num == 0)

            return 0;

        else if (num == 1)

            return 1;

        else

            for (int x3 = 0; x3 < num; x3++)
                {
                    x3 = x1 + x2;
                    x1 = x2;
                    x2 = x3;
                }
                return x3;

}
  }
```

There are probably other problems I've missed. I'm pretty new to java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: x3 doesn't exist outside the for loop

Comment: So instead of declaring x3 within the loop I would declare it outside?

Comment: Yeah declaring it outside fixed that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fibcalc()` method has a single `int` parameter, but you are calling it with *two* parameters.

Change the call from

```
fibcalc(num, x3)
```

to

```
fibcalc(num)
```

ie change that line to:

```
System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %f", num, fibcalc(num));
```

---

Also, if you want accurate numbers for your results, change from using `double` to using [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which can handle arbitrarily large numbers accurately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute Fibonacci numbers, you can use direct (non-recursive, non-iterative) [formula for Fibonacci numbers](https://web.archive.org/web/20170829141954/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52686.html):

```
Fib(n) = (pow((1+sqrt(5))/2, n) + pow((1-sqrt(5))/2, n)) / sqrt(5)
```

It turns out that for all `n >= 0`, you can simplify this formula to:

```
Fib(n) = round(pow((1+sqrt(5))/2, n) / sqrt(5))
```

Knowing this, you can use following simple implementation for `fibcalc`:

```
public static double fibcalc(int num) {
    return Math.floor(Math.pow((1+Math.sqrt(5))/2, num) / Math.sqrt(5) + 0.5);
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this and got the error "Possible loos of precision required int found: long. Am I supposed to change public static int to public static long?

Comment: This is weird. In my example there is no `long` anywhere. Look at this working example at [IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/emxMKV). It compiles without warnings and works fine

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. It gives me a strange answer if I enter anything above 70, which it is not supposed to do.

Comment: @user1858350: I have updated my answer to use `Math.floor(x+0.5)` (`double` type) instead of `Math.round(x)` (`long` type) - this was breaking down after n>92. Now it works for `n` well beyond `100`: [**ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/ZNuAFC)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following calculator to calculate the Fibonacci sequence (using Javascript): [enter link description here](http://www.convertforfree.com/fibonacci-sequence-calculator/)

Comment: Hello, while providing a link to another post is beneficial, the answer should contain the solution. Please add more detail.