# what does int numbers[n+2]; statement do?

Tags: c++, fibonacci, function-definition

```
  #include<iostream>

    int fastFibonacci(int n) 
    {
      int numbers[n+2]; // int numbers[n].
      numbers[0] = 0;
      numbers[1] = 1;
      for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
      {
          numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1] + numbers[i - 2];
      }
      return numbers[n];
    }

    int main() {
      int n;
      std::cout << "Enter a Number";
      std::cin >> n;
      int result = fastFibonacci(n);
      std::cout << result << "\n";
      return 0;
    }
```

in this code when i enter input 0 or 1 get correct answer. But the problem is that when i replace **int numbers[n+2];** with the commented part it start giving me wrong answer when input is 0 or 1. why? anyone please explain me.

Comment: It is a non-standard C++ feature of declaring a variable length array. This is just a bad code and nothing more.:)

Comment: ok i understand but can u explain me that statement int numbers[n+2];

Comment: *in this code when i enter input 0 or 1 get correct answer.* -- You're lucky, since this code doesn't compile for Visual Studio all due to the non-standard C++ syntax.

Comment: @Desg Aman This is a declaration of an array with n + 2 elements.

Comment: oh okay thanks for the help i'm a beginner so that's why i'm making mistakes hoping for good, thank you so much for your help

Comment: Side note: With `T array [n]`, `array[i]` is only valid if  0 <= `i` < `n`. `array[n]` would access out of bounds. In this case that +2 gives the extra space required and one more for good measure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int numbers[n+2];` is the declaration of an array of `int`s with space for `n` + 2 `int`s, [this is a variable lenght array and is not part of C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/6865932), though some compilers allow it it's not somenthing you should use.

If you need a variable lenght array use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

With `int numbers[n+2];` if `n` is equal to 0 you still have space for 2 `int`s, if you have `int numbers[n];` the array will have space for 0 `int`s, so the code will fail because you are trying to access memory that does not exist with `numbers[0]` and `numbers[1]`.

There are several good ways to implement the Fibonacci sequence, in the site you can find many questions regarding this matter in several programming languages, here is one of them [Fibonacci series in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718677/6865932)

**Edit**

So I've seen your comments about using a vector, for making the sequence you wouldn't need the vector just two variables to store the two numbers to add, to store the sequence in a vactor, you can do somenthing like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

//passing the vector by reference
void fastFibonacci(unsigned long long n, std::vector<unsigned long long>& sequence) {

   unsigned long long first = 0;
   unsigned long long second = 1;
   sequence.push_back(first); //add first values to the vector
   sequence.push_back(second); //add first values to the vector
   for (unsigned long long i = 0, value = 0; i < n && value <= LLONG_MAX ; ++i) {
      value = first + second;
      first = second;
      second = value;
      sequence.push_back(value); //adding values to the vector
   }  
}

int main() {  
   unsigned long long limit; //number of values in the sequence
   int num = 1;
   std::vector<unsigned long long> sequence; //container for the sequence

   std::cout << "Enter upper limit: ";
   std::cin >> limit;
   fastFibonacci(limit, sequence);

   //print the sequence in a range based loop formatted with <iomanip> library
   for(auto& i : sequence){
      std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::left << num++ << " " << i << std::endl; 
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If you want to print just one of the numbers in the sequence, just use, for instance:

```
std::cout << sequence[10];
```

Instead of the whole vector.

The code you post in the comment to the other answer won't work because the access to the vector is out of bounds in `numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1] + numbers[i - 2];`, if for instance `i = 5`, your vector only has 2 nodes but you are accessing the 6th node `numbers[5]`.

Comment: @DesgAman, you're welcome I added to the answer to address your question regarding `int numbers[n];`.

Comment: @DesgAman, I saw your comment in the other answer, I posted a possible solution and the reasons why the new code is ill-formed, I hope it helps, if you have any doubts you can ask.

Answer (score 2):

In this function

```
int fastFibonacci(int n) 
{
  int numbers[n+2]; // int numbers[n].
  numbers[0] = 0;
  numbers[1] = 1;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
  {
      numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1] + numbers[i - 2];
  }
  return numbers[n];
}
```

there is used a variable length array with `n + 2` elements declared in this line

```
  int numbers[n+2]; // int numbers[n].
```

Variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. It can be implemented as  own language extension of a C++ compiler.

Using the variable length array makes the function very unsafe because there can occur a stack overflow.

As within the function there is explicitly used two elements of the array

```
  numbers[0] = 0;
  numbers[1] = 1;
```

then the array shall have at least two elements even when the parameter has a value less than 2.

To calculate the n-th Fibonacci number there is no need to declare an array of such a size.

Apart from this the function argument shall have an unsigned integer type. Otherwise the function can invoke undefined behavior if the user passes a negative number.

Also for big values of `n` there can be an integer overflow for the type `int`.

The function can be implemented in various ways.

Here is one of possible its implementations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

unsigned long long fibonacci( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned long long a[] = { 0, 1 };

    while ( n-- )
    {
        a[1] += std::exchange( a[0], a[1] );
    }

    return a[0];
}

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << fibonacci( i ) << '\n'; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 5
6: 8
7: 13
8: 21
9: 34
```

Comment: Thankyou. Can you please tell me that did i do this correct this time                                  
    `int fastFibonacci2(int n) {
      std::vector<unsigned long int> numbers;
      numbers.push_back(0);
      numbers.push_back(1);
      for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
      {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1] + numbers[i - 2];
      }
      return numbers[n];
    }`

Comment: @DesgAman Why are you asking me? You selected already the best answer. The idea with std::vector is bad. This approach is inefficient. I showed in my answer how the function can be simpler implemented. And presented by you code has undefined behavior because you may not use the subscript operator with non-existent elements of the vector.

Comment: I am asking you because I find your answer also very helpful. It doesn't mean that if I selected the best answer your answer is bad. I appreciate you for helping me.